# Placing items selectively in a post method to XML, any thoughts?

Tags: php, html, css, xml, feed

A friend had created an awesome PHP script for me that generates XML tags when submitting text from an input field to an XML file. I'm running into a few issue when trying to render that XML data as RSS. I have written the XML differently to be viewed as RSS, but when ever my input field posts text to the XML file it should place inside the item tag but instead it places it after the closing channel tag. Any thought on how to fix that?

feed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <rss version="2.0">
 <channel>
          <item>
                    <title>Hello</title>
         </item>
  </channel>
  <title>Hello again!</title>
  </rss>
```

user.php

```
    <?php

    if ($_POST['post']) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('feed.xml');
        $xml->addChild('title', $_POST['post']);

        file_put_contents('feed.xml', $xml->asXML());
    }
    ?>


    <div class="feed">
    <form action="" method="post">
    <textarea rows="5" cols="42" name="post" class="post" placeholder="What's up?">
    </textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Post">
    </form>
    <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get the rss node and append to that.  I think somethign like the following should work:

```
$rss_node = $xml->getElementByName('rss');
$new_node = $rss_node->createElement('title');
$rss_node->appendChild($new_node);
```

[How do I add new elements to XML using PHP DOM deeper than the root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727132/how-do-i-add-new-elements-to-xml-using-php-dom-deeper-than-the-root)

Comment: What would go into (your_data), the link to the file or the XML tag?

Comment: I updated, you have to create the title node, Add the text that you want to the title node, then append it to the rss node. And that should solve your problem

Comment: Okay, just replace that with the current $xml method?