# php xml DOMDocument append

Tags: php, xml

Hello guys i was searching how to select xml element and append it

but i didn't find any thing 
[image: xml pic]

```
<classes>
    <class name="A" grade="10">
        <student age="16">Martin</student>
    </class>
    <class name="B" grade="10">
        <student age="16">Justin</student>
    </class>
</classes>
```

For example i want to select class by tag name
then append student element to it
and that is just what i want to know for now.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyourtried.com)

Comment: i was looking here it didnt work with me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727132/how-do-i-add-new-elements-to-xml-using-php-dom-deeper-than-the-root

Answer (score 1):

Can you use jQuery?  If so, the solution is pretty simple.  Where `XML` is your XML document

```
$(xml).children('class[name="A"]').append(studentElement);
```